# Filter div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to filter some div with an input field : 
I want to show all divs at the beginning and when user types into the input field, filter by the `<p class="name"></p>`

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<input type="text"  class="filter" id="myInput" placeholder="Recherche rapide...">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
  <div class="card all-patients" id="">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="row" id="">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center m-b-0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 m-b-0">
   <p class="name">John Doe</p>
   <p> 12 ans</p>
   <p> 04 94 94 94 94</p>
   <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-cyan">Fiche du patient</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id=""  style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
  <div class="card all-patients" id="">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="row" id="">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center m-b-0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 m-b-0">
   <p class="name">Samuel pelo</p>
   <p> 12 ans</p>
   <p> 04 94 94 94 94</p>
   <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-cyan">Fiche du patient</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the javascript code you have written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution filter divs with names that contains value from input. Filtering is case-insensitive. Also, there is no setting any class, but if you need you can add this. Just change `$card.show()` to `$card.addClass('visible')` and change `$card.hide()` to `$card.removeClass('visible')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.filter').on('input', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $cards = $('.card');

    $filteredCards = $cards.each(function(i, card) {
      var $card = $(card);
      var name = $card.find('.name').first();
      name = name.text().toLowerCase();

      if(name.indexOf($this.val().toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        $card.show();
      } else {
        $card.hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="filter" id="myInput" placeholder="Recherche rapide...">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
  <div class="card all-patients" id="">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="row" id="">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center m-b-0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 m-b-0">
          <p class="name">John Doe</p>
          <p> 12 ans</p>
          <p> 04 94 94 94 94</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-cyan">Fiche du patient</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
  <div class="card all-patients" id="">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="row" id="">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center m-b-0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 m-b-0">
          <p class="name">Samuel pelo</p>
          <p> 12 ans</p>
          <p> 04 94 94 94 94</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-cyan">Fiche du patient</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Assuming you need to filter with `startsWith`.
- Use a class `hide` to hide the elements.
- Loop over each `.body` elements.
- Find the elements using this selector `[class="name"]`.
- Compare the text using `startsWith` function.

## Look at this code snippet.

```js
//<p class="name">John Doe</p>

$('#myInput').on('input', function() {
  var enteredValue = $(this).val();

  $('.body').each(function() {
    var $parent = $(this);
    $(this).find('[class="name"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().startsWith(enteredValue)) {
        $parent.removeClass('hide');
      } else {
        $parent.addClass('hide');
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="filter" id="myInput" placeholder="Recherche rapide...">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
  <div class="card all-patients" id="">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="row" id="">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center m-b-0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 m-b-0">
          <p class="name">John Doe</p>
          <p> 12 ans</p>
          <p> 04 94 94 94 94</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-cyan">Fiche du patient</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
  <div class="card all-patients" id="">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="row" id="">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center m-b-0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 m-b-0">
          <p class="name">Samuel pelo</p>
          <p> 12 ans</p>
          <p> 04 94 94 94 94</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-cyan">Fiche du patient</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See? the elements are being filtered.