# Select with php and strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime

I have issue with strotime function in php...
Here is html example of what i expect.

```html
<select>
    <option value="2018-02-26" selected>Feb 26 - March 4</option>
    <option value="2018-02-19">Feb 19 - Feb 25</option>
    <option value="2018-02-12">Feb 12 - Feb 18</option>
    <option value="2018-02-05">Feb 05 - Feb 11</option>
</select>
```

And here my php code.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
   $option_value = '' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("this monday - $i week")) . '' . " / " . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("this sunday - $i week")).' / '.$i;
   $option_render = date("d/m", strtotime("this monday - $i week")) . " / " . date("d/m", strtotime("this sunday - $i week ")) . '';

}
```

The problem is that the php code is not rendering what i want...
Here is the result of php :

```html
<select>
   <option value="2018-03-05">05/03 / 04/03</option>
   <option value="2018-02-26">26/02 / 25/02</option>
   <option value="2018-02-19">19/02 / 18/02</option>
   <option value="2018-02-12">12/02 / 11/02</option>
   <option value="2018-02-05">05/02 / 04/02</option>
   <option value="2018-01-29">29/01 / 28/01</option>
   <option value="2018-01-22">22/01 / 21/01</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question or describe your problem. _"I have issue"_ is quite vague

Comment: and since you're just building that: better use the 'new' [DateTime Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). It's easier, clearer, better to maintain, ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48608841/1415724 that other question of yours still open?

Comment: yeah im new i just close it i guess :)

Comment: `date('M d', strtotime....)` - here's [the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: and replace `" / "` with `" - "`

Comment: This is not about the render of date, i just set up an quick example... My issue is with 05/03 / 04/03 , 26/02 / 25/02, etc...

Comment: I just could guess what your problem is. I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
     $option_value = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("this monday - $i week"));
     $option_render = date("M d", strtotime("this monday - ".($i+1)." week")) . " - " . date("M d", strtotime("this sunday - $i week "));
}
```

Check this out, testing output:

```
2018-03-05 ~ Feb 26 - Mar 04
2018-02-26 ~ Feb 19 - Feb 25
2018-02-19 ~ Feb 12 - Feb 18
2018-02-12 ~ Feb 05 - Feb 11
2018-02-05 ~ Jan 29 - Feb 04
2018-01-29 ~ Jan 22 - Jan 28
2018-01-22 ~ Jan 15 - Jan 21
```